# What word begins with "s" and means "seperated from religion"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What word begins with a letter "***s***" and means "seperated from religion"

Answer (score 1):

## *secular*

It took me several minutes to remember the word. I am posting both the question and answer so that if someone uses a search engine, like Google, to look for a word starting in "s" and meaning non-religious, that person might find this answer.

Comment: You might also edit the title and question to reflect the correct spelling of ***separate***